# Summing up BigDecimal in a map of list of objects in Java

Tags: java, java-stream, bigdecimal

I'm stuck with some elegant ways to get a summation of `BigDecimal`s in a map. I know how to calculate the sum in a map of `BigDecimal` but not a List of object with a `BigDecimal`.

The structure of my objects are as below:

```
Class Obj {
  private BigDecimal b;
  // Getter for b, say getB()
}

Map<String, List<Obj>> myMap;
```

I need to get a sum of all `b`s in `myMap`. Looking for some elegant ways to do this in Java, may be using streams?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Stream the values of the `Map`.
2. Use [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) to flatten the stream of lists of `BigDecimal`s to a stream of `BigDecimal`s.
3. Use `map` to extract the `BigDecimal`s.
4. Use `reduce` with a summing operation.

```
BigDecimal sum = myMap.values().stream()
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .map(Obj::getB)
            .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, (a, b) -> a.add(b) );
```

The [`Stream.reduce` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) takes an identity value (for summing values, zero), and a `BinaryOperator` that adds intermediate results together.

You may also use a method reference in place of the lambda above: `BigDecimal::add`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. This works. Can also use BigDecimal::add instead of (a, b) -> a.add(b) I guess.

Comment: Or use `.reduce(BigDecimal::add).orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO)`, which saves you one operation.

Answer (score 3):

```
BigDecimal sum = myMap.values()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .map(Obj::getB)
    .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```